# Java date format conversions with localization

Tags: java, simpledateformat, datetime-format

I want to convert my epoch time to the below format.

`Tuesday, 29th of August, 12:30 PM`

I am trying to use DateTimeFormatter

```
final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
                .ofPattern("cccc, dd MMMM, hh:mm a")
                .withZone(ZoneId.of(timezone)).withLocale(locale);
```

Now, how can I get 'of' in my output? And that too, localized? 
For instance, in Spanish, I want it as

`martes, 29 de agosto, 12:30 PM.`

Comment: You will need to use a [ResourceBundle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html), which allows you to store each locale’s format string in a separate property file or separate class.

Comment: You can add any text literal to the pattern in single quotes. The difficult part is the "th" suffix and translation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to automatically localize the date-time format language and styling, let `DateTimeFormatter` class determine the formatter by calling the `ofLocalized…` methods.

To localize, specify:

- [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

Example code…

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of( 2017 , 8 , 29 , 12 , 30 );

Locale localeUS = Locale.US;
Locale localeCanadaFrench = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH;
Locale localeSpain = new Locale( "es" , "ES" );

DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.MEDIUM );

String outputUS = ldt.format( f.withLocale( localeUS ) );
String outputCanadaFrench = ldt.format( f.withLocale( localeCanadaFrench ) );
String outputSpain = ldt.format( f.withLocale( localeSpain ) );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "outputUS: " + outputUS );
System.out.println( "outputCanadaFrench: " + outputCanadaFrench );
System.out.println( "outputSpain: " + outputSpain );
```

> outputUS: Aug 29, 2017, 12:30:00 PM
>
> outputCanadaFrench: 29 août 2017 12:30:00
>
> outputSpain: 29 ago. 2017 12:30:00

For a format style of `LONG` or `FULL`, you need to assign a time zone.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of( 2017 , 8 , 29 , 12 , 30 );
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z );

Locale localeUS = Locale.US;
Locale localeCanadaFrench = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH;
Locale localeSpain = new Locale( "es" , "ES" );

DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL );

String outputUS = zdt.format( f.withLocale( localeUS ) );
String outputCanadaFrench = zdt.format( f.withLocale( localeCanadaFrench ) );
String outputSpain = zdt.format( f.withLocale( localeSpain ) );
```

> outputUS: Tuesday, August 29, 2017 at 12:30:00 PM New Zealand Standard Time
>
> outputCanadaFrench: mardi 29 août 2017 à 12:30:00 heure normale de la Nouvelle-Zélande
>
> outputSpain: martes, 29 de agosto de 2017, 12:30:00 (hora estándar de Nueva Zelanda)

## Ordinal numbering

I have not noticed any [ordinal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number_(linguistics)) (such as `th`, `nd`, `rd`, etc.) appearing in any of the localizations that I’ve seen.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Upvoted for the detailed answers! I was able to localize the string, but the ordinal numbers were missing. And that is what I was interested in! Cheers for your answer!